# Error Calling Python module function DbMySQLFE.connect

Tags: migration, mysql-workbench, odbc

Migrating a database from SqlServer to Mysql using "MySQL WorkBench 6.3 CE" using ODBC data source as default methode to use to connect to the RDBMS.

-> Source Selection Test connection is Successful 
-> Target Selection Test Connection gives Error Calling Python module function DbMySQLFE.connect
I have researched alot and few folks blaming SSH connection over TCP. If its the case Can I disable SSH over TCP??
I have attached the Screenshot. Please respond its really urgent. thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Workbench version < 8.x cannot login to a MySQL server when a cached sha2 password is used for that user. This auth method has been made the default only recently right before the 8.0.11 server was released. All new accounts will have this auth method unless you switched this off in your server config.

Download the MySQL Workbench release 8.0.11 RC to be able to use such accounts (this is a development release) or use the command line to change the auth method for that user to native, which will allow older Workbench versions to login.